# Why does this error "ImportError: cannot import name 'float8_e4m3fn' from 'tensorflow.python.framework.dtypes'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, training-data

When i try to import tensorflow the error appears.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'float8_e4m3fn' from 'tensorflow.python.framework.dtypes' (C:\RealTimeObjectDetection\TFODmodel\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py)
```

it worked before, that's why i don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Try and run the following command which upgrades your package.

```py
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

If the issue remains, the thing you are trying to import probably does not exist, or it is in another namepace.